# WebClient и загрузка изображений

Tags: c#, веб-программирование

Хочу загрузить 
[изображение](http://hoff.ru/upload/iblock/68a/68aee4ef7945d114602385931618a070.jpg), для чего использую примерно следующий код

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFile(url, Folder + "/" + sub_path + "/" + fileName);
```

Первый параметр - `url`, второй - путь к папке. В `fileName` название изображения (в данном случае `68aee4ef7945d114602385931618a070.jpg`).

В результате картинка скачивается, но при попытке открыть получаю такой результат:

[image]

Пробовал передавать заголовки по аналогии с запросом от браузера - результат тот же.

```
client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Referer, url);
client.Headers.Add("Host: hoff.ru");
client.Headers.Add("Cache-Control: max-age=0");
client.Headers.Add("Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4");
client.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, lzma, sdch");
client.Headers.Add("Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
```

Никаких исключений не генерируется. С других сайтов картинки скачиваются без проблем...
В чем может быть проблема? Что тут можно предпринять?

Comment: Сниффер, что говорит?

Comment: http://joxi.ru/ZrJE6y8teeo9Aj а на какую именно информацию мне следует обратить внимание? или может посоветуете сниффер какой-нибудь? что нужно сделать?

Comment: необходимо обратить внимание на содержимое header браузера и вашей программы, так сказать найти 10 различий. Иногда проблема кроется в этом! У вас нормальный сниффер, для таких целей пойдет!

Сразу бросается в глаза Cookie.

Попробуйте зайти с другого браузера и посмотреть, какая картина там. Возможно, эмуляция IE будет более простой, чем Firefox. UserAgent так же задайте у WebClient.